# What could cause solid state relay failure over and over on 1 HP 120VAC motor?

Tags: solid-state-relay

[image]
I have a well pump (~6.5 A) setup with a remote smart device, and currently a 40 A solid state relay.
I previously had a 25 A solid state relay.
The solid state relay is failing frequently (few days) in the 'ON' state (very bad). Despite the fact that my smart controller gives clear off/on state indications, and the energized LED indicator on the SSR is off. Maybe an inductive load issue? When powered on, this motor only operates intermittently for 20-40 second intervals, 8-10 times/day.

The SSR is connected in series with the circuit breaker in the power distribution panel for this pump. There are no further details beyond what is presented here.  Very simple.

This SSR is currently in place and failing: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01MCWO35P?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MCWO35P)

Are there any alternatives other than a conventional high current relay/contactor?
Any guidance greatly appreciated

Comment: Buy a reputable brand through a reputable dealer. "*No datasheet? No sale!*" Observe the manufacturer's recommendations for switching motors which have a very high starting current (due to the lack of back EMF while accelerating from rest). Also check recommendations on snubbing inductive loads.

Comment: The off-brand made in China and sold on Amazon should be your first clue. But please show your setup with a schematic or block diagram.

Comment: 2nd clue: the description says it is made for temperature control, implying a resistive load.

Comment: The 'Temperature control' reference appears to be for the included heat sink.  The other SSRs sold without heat sinks have no such wording. Such as this previous unit <https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01N1MMSKI/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o08_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1>.  I'm getting educated a bit here <https://www3.panasonic.biz/ac/e/control/relay/solid-state/cautions_use/index.jsp>

Comment: Any progress on the schematic and/or block diagram?

Comment: There have been a lot of counterfeit SSRs around. I would recommend never using them in high current applications. https://protosupplies.com/inferior-counterfeit-fotek-ssr-25-solid-state-relays-on-the-market/.  Most well pumps use contactors not SSRs and they seem to be pretty reliable. Youtuber Matthias Wandel used an SSR to switch a hot water heater and it failed in a smoldering ruin on top of his water heater.

Comment: Also, single phase motors have very high startup currents. The startup current could very easily be exceeding the 25 or even 40 A limit briefly.

Answer (score 2):

Some Chinese devices use undersized components that will fail when subjected to a fraction of rated load. Also, such TRIAC/SCR SSRs may not be rated for inductive (motor) loads. And if this relay has zero crossing firing, it will exhibit much larger initial surge current that may cause eventual failure. Of course those with random firing angle will sometimes exhibit this behavior, and peak firing SSRs for inductive loads are rare and expensive.

This company makes peak firing SSRs: https://carlogavazzisales.com/pdfs/switchingprod/ssr.pdf

There are circuits that can provide ZC firing. By adding a 90 degree phase shift network ( RC integrator or differentiator) the phase reference can be shifted to provide peak firing. Designing and implementing such a design is beyond the scope of this question, but would be appropriate if the OP wanted to pursue that idea.

You could measure the voltage drop across the load terminals with the pump running to see if it is too high, indicating undersized TRIAC or SCR. A snubber might protect against inductive kick, but since TRIACs and SCRs stop conducting at zero current, that is probably not the problem.

Comment: I received a reply from a Sensata/Crydom applications engineer.  He recommended their model D-1225-10 SSR  (https://assets.alliedelec.com/v1575458042/Datasheets/a02c258be28dd9ba64b9ce8aec33f223.pdf) with the Instantaneous Turn On feature. I have one ordered from Allied...

Comment: Instantaneous turn on is not the same as ZC turn-on. Unless you use an external circuit to delay firing 90 degrees from a ZC, the turn-on phase will be random. If the SSR is rated for a sufficiently high peak current, the turn-on phase might not be critical. But it would be good to monitor the current with a scope to see how large the peak might be.

Answer (score 1):

Not all SSRs can be used for motor starting. You want to find an SSR that is rated specifically for motor starting. It may be called a "contactor." Usually relays (including SSRs) that are rated for starting single-phase motors will be called "contactors" rather than "relays." These will be rated for the size motor they can operate. For example in the US, small ones may be rated at 1 HP (1 Horsepower). If the specifications for the SSR or contactor do not specifically mention motor power or say that it may be used for motor starting, do not use it.

When a single-phase motor starts there is a brief very high current until the motor gets up near its rated speed. Perhaps this motor start transient is over-stressing your SSR. One allen bradley SSR contactor I found is rated for 1.5 HP but the current rating is 43 Amps. So that may give you an idea of how much de-rating is needed for reliable operation of a motor.

In addition, there are a LOT of counterfeit SSRs around. I have heard of a number of problems caused by counterfeit SSRs. They look just about exactly like the originals.

Personally, I would absolutely never use an SSR for starting a well pump. Electromechanical well pump contactors work just fine for that purpose and last a long time and are not too expensive. But if you must use an SSR contactor, buy from a reliable source and reliable manufacturer who has taken the trouble to put out a data sheet or guide so you can confirm that you are within the intended application range.

Comment: mkeith, I', looking at prominent brands now like Omron, Opto22, IDEC, Panasonic, Crydom trying to get answers, find products and spec sheets.  Not so easy.

Comment: If they are marketed as contactors and have a HP rating, you can feel OK about it even without a spec sheet.